# How to match a inputted password to hashed password from database?

Tags: php, authentication, php-password-hash

For some reasons, I don't know if I am really getting the hashed password from the database or if I am comparing it right to the inputted password. I have successfully tested my registration with the `password_hash` method and I am seeing the hashed password in the database.

Should I also hash the inputted password to be compared to the hashed password from the database? Or my query is just wrong? Please help!!! Thanks!

```
<?php
require "../connection.php";

session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    $query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") OR DIE(mysqli_error($conn));
    $reader = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($reader == 1) {
            $passwordQuery = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") OR DIE(mysqli_error($conn));
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($passwordQuery);
            $hashedPasswordFromDb = $row['password'];
            if (password_verify($password, $hashedPasswordFromDb)) {
                $query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT id, student_number FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") OR DIE(mysqli_error($conn));
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $id = $row['id'];
                $student_number = $row['student_number'];
                $sesData = array('id' => $id, 'student_number', $student_number);
                $_SESSION['ses_account'] = $sesData;
                mysqli_query ($conn, "UPDATE admin SET lastLogin=NOW() WHERE student_number='$student_number'");
                header("location: dashboard.php");
            } else {
                $msg="User not recognized. Please try again.";
                urlencode($msg);
                header("location: ../index.php?errmsg=$msg");
            }
        } else {
            $msg="User not recognized. Please try again.";
            urlencode($msg);
            header("location: ../index.php?errmsg=$msg");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are storing hashed passwords into the database (that's good)

but here:

```
$query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") OR DIE(mysqli_error($conn));
```

you are fetching the user comparing a hashed password with a plain-text one. So the query will never return any row/user.

---

Here is how you should proceed to implement a **very basic** system for **1** registering a user and **2** check for login.

First of all use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of sanityzing input and then injecting strings into the query. You'll end up with **safer** and more readable code.

**1** When you register a new user store the username and the hashed (and possibly **[salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))**) password into the db.

**2** When you check for login, hash/elaborate the plain text password you get as input (with the **same process** you implemented when performing registration) then make a single `SELECT` to get the user by username and finally check hashed password matches.

---

Assuming you're at least on PHP 5.5 use [**password_hash**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [**password_verify**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to hash the password (`password_hash`) and check a plaintext password with a hashed one (`password_verify`)

Further reading here: [**Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: This was very informative, I have to thank you for that. But unfortunately,  it is still not logging in. I have tried hashing the user-inputted password and just made a single query as you suggested.

`$hashedPasswordInput = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`



`$query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$hashedPasswordInput'") OR DIE(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: I'm not able to fix your code with the information provided and code shown (and usually it's your job to do that, on SO normally you get help in doing that). Try to narrow down  /isolate the part of code that is broken. **What is the test that fails ?** `if (password_verify($password, $hashedPasswordFromDb))` ? Finally, show us the code you use to hash the password upon registration. Maybe I or someone else may give further help.

Comment: I got it to work! This phrase:

**make a single SELECT to get the user by username**

got it to work! I did not notice this. Thanks, really!